# Correct blockquote markup and CSS Style

Tags: html, css, quotes, semantic-markup

I read two things about blockquotes:

1. The cite-tag has to be inside the blockquote-tag
2. Quotationmarks are not part of semntic layout. That makes sense, as I don't want the user to take care of correct quotation. Eg. if I want to use Guillemets.

That leads to a problem. If I want it to look that way:

```
"Blockquotes are an essential part of a fancy website."
                                                – Cite
```

The markup would look like this:

```
<blockquote><p>Blockquotes are an essential part of a fancy website."</p>
<cite>Cite</cite></blockquote>
```

I could use the :before and :after elements to add the quotationmarks and the dash. But what if I have two paragraphs? I could wrap them into a span, but at that point, it really gets too complicated for my users to take care of it. (Plus: Wordpress does not even have a way to add a cite-tag, but thats another story)

How would you solve this? What is your HTML-Markup for a correct blockquote and how do you add the quotationmarks?

Comment: I assume you mean using before and after on the `<p>`? I wonder if you could mix it with some first-child and last-child selectors... not sure on browser support though.

Comment: You are right! The support is better than that of :before and :after. I should have thought about this. Maybe you can post it as an answer.

Comment: What is the "Cite" supposed to be? I'm not sure you are using the `<cite>` element right. Were you thinking of the `cite` _attribute_?

Comment: I think it's this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite

Comment: As far as I understand it can be used, for example, to contain the Newspaper in which the quote was printed. (– New York Times) And that's, how I use it. If you want to have something like - Mark Twain, you can use another tag, I think in that case it has to be outside the blockquote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
blockquote p:first-of-type:before {
    content:"\00AB";
    font-size:1.5em;
}

blockquote p:last-of-type:after {
    content:"\00BB";
    font-size:1.5em;}

cite:before {
    content:"\2014"
}
```

This uses guillemets and an mdash to format the output.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9LjTB/1/

Comment: for guillements we'll need an escaped \uWhatsit so it outputs properly... just trying to find the correct code, then I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

(EDIT: Note that the definition of both elements, `blockquote` and `cite`, changed in [HTML 5.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-html51-20131029/) recently; this answer reflects the *current* HTML5 state, not the changed HTML 5.1 one.)

---

The `cite` element must **not** be part of the `blockquote` (unless you quote a quote+attribution). `blockquote` must only contain quoted content, not the quotation author/source.

[HTML5 spec for `blockquote`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element):

> Attribution for the quotation, if any, must be placed outside the blockquote element.

So it should be:

```
<blockquote>…</blockquote>
<cite>…</cite>
```

Note that in HTML5, the [`cite` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element) may be used only for the "title of a work"; so it’s likely that you want to use a `div`, possibly containing `cite`:

```
<blockquote>…</blockquote>
<div class="quote-attribution">Walter White, <cite>Breaking Bad</cite></div>
```